# How to send an Attachment in Google Chat via Bot/ Webhook

Tags: google-chat

My organisation is using Google Chat for internal communication. In one of the group in the app I am sending the report of daily automation test run using [webhook](https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/webhooks). Currently the report consist of only text message containing the pass/ fail count.

But I want to send the html report as well with that. I could not found any source which tell the information about how to send the attachment in the bot messages in Google chat.

Please help me if someone knows how to send the attachment report using Google Chat Bot or Webhook.

Answer (score 2):

Per documentation, [Bots have limited message types](https://developers.google.com/chat/concepts/cards#from_bots) they can send. (Only simple text, or Cards)

I would suggest sending a link to download the report, which is feasible with the bot. See [Including links in message text](https://developers.google.com/chat/reference/message-formats/basic#including_links_in_message_text)